# How to create custom syntax highlighting without Yoeman Generators?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

I tried to install Yeoman using npm, but it gave me errors that I don't know how to fix.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\msys64\home\446870/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\msys64\home\446870\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\446870\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-24T21_11_38_702Z-debug-0.log
```

So I'm wondering if there's a way to create custom syntax highlighting without the generator.

Comment: you only need a `package.json` with a contribution of a TextMate grammar file

Comment: Ok, after putting in the package.json and trying to install yo, it removed my npm files. Every single one of them. It could be because I put the arg -g...

Comment: don't use `yo`, I never used it for any of my extensions, just start with the hello-world example extension